# Nil Error when initializing variable

Tags: swift, xcode

I updated my app to the newest SWIFT version in XCode 8.2.1 via the automatic update of the code.

Now my app crashes when I init a variable:

```
var sndAlgo1 = URL(string: "")!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    self.startAudioPlayerWithURL(self.sndAlgo1)
}

func initializeSounds() {
    self.sndAlgo1 = self.createAudioFilePath("Algo1", type: "mp3")
    self.sndAlgo2 = self.createAudioFilePath("Algo2", type: "mp3")
    self.sndNotruf = self.createAudioFilePath("Notruf", type: "mp3")
    self.sndLoop = self.createAudioFilePath("Loop", type: "mp3")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.btnEmergencyClicked = false
    self.initializeSounds()
}
```

> 2017-03-25 08:18:58.718804 TUMCPR[813:153254] fatal error:
>   unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Is there any different way now to init these kind of vars?

Comment: An URL created with an empty string is not valid even in older Swift versions.

Comment: How would be the correct way then?

Answer (score 0):

If the URLs are treated as constants and the sound files are located in the bundle create the URLs directly on the top level of the class, for example:

```
let sndAlgo1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Algo1", withExtension: "mp3")!
let sndNotruf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Notruf", withExtension: "mp3")!
```

Answer (score 0):

You got an error because you unwrapped a nil value (`URL(string: "")` returns a nil value). Let create an **implicitly unwrapped optional variable** like this: `var sndAlgo1: URL!`